# can't access content on wordpress, always redirected to the page http://localhost/dashboard/

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

I just tried to moving my live wordpress to localhost, everything looks okay. But when i try to access content in my website, localhost always direct me to the page localhost/dashboard. can somebody help me ?

Comment: Did you change the URL on the database?

Comment: I did, I change option_value site url and home on wpus_options.

I've also entered the script :

UPDATE wpus_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://mywebsite/', 'http://localhost/mylocalfile') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wpus_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://mywebsite/', 'http://localhost/mylocalfile');
UPDATE wpus_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://mywebsite/','http://localhost/mylocalfile');